# Is there a proof that 1+0=1?

Tags: arithmetic, education

I was wondering is it possible to prove 1+0=1(or 0+1=1)? If yes! how does it look like! Does it even make sense to ask for proof here? My google searches didn't turn up anything.

Thanks.

Comment: The former is basically the definition of '+' and '0'. The latter also needs the definition of '1'. Look up Peano axioms. But yeah, in some sense this cannot be proved.

Comment: You can only prove things within a system with defined axioms an definitions.  In nearly all mathematical systems the definition of $0$ is that $0$ is the additive identity; that is $0$ is defined to be a number so that $a+0 = 0 + a = a$ always.  $0+1=1$ by definition.  But it may vary for different systems.

Comment: If you can tell me how you defined "+" and $0$, I can tell you if $0+1 = 1$ is something to prove or something defined by axiom.  Jyrki Lahtonen makes an interesting comment that in the Peano postulates that $a+0=a$ is axiomatic but you must prove that $0+a=a$ (and that $a+b = b+a$).  In group theory $a+0=0+a = a$ is an axiom.

Comment: In Peano arithmetic you start with things like  $x+0=x$ and $x+S(y)=S(x+y)$ and $1=S(0)$.  The first of these gives $1+0=1$ immediately, while combined they give $0+1=0+S(0)=S(0+0)=S(0)=1$

Answer (score 0):

$x+0=0+x=x$ is an axiom in Peano arithmetic's implicit definition of the addition of non-negative integers. We set $x=1$ for the proof.

Comment: When I learned Peano axioms $x+0=x$ was true by definition. On the other hand $0+x=x$ required a proof by induction on $x$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Typically either $0+x$ or $x+0$ will be mentioned in the definition; the rest follows when you prove commutativity.